# How to include a random perturbation noise in initial solution by numerical simulation

Tags: matlab, physics, numerical-methods, numerical-analysis

I am solving NLSE equation with a potential term in matlab by split-step method. I want to see solution in it numerically. u=sech(x) is the initial guess solution in that numerical algorithm. But I want to add 10% random perturbation to this initial guess solution in matlab. How to do it? Is it like:

```
u=sech(x)+10/100*cos(x)
```

where the random perturbation is sinusoidal.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to specify what exactly you mean by 10% random perturbation. If you just want to add white noise centred at the actual values of `u`, you could do the below

```
% sample x values
x = 0:0.01:5;

noise_fraction = 0.1; % 10%
% the actual values
u=sech(x);
% the noise
u_noise = noise_fraction*u.*(rand(size(x))-0.5);

figure(1);cla(gca);
hold on;
nh = plot(x, u_noise);
ch = plot(x, u + u_noise);
sh = plot(x, u);
hold off;
legend([sh, nh, ch,], {'Signal', 'Noise', 'Combined'});
```

You should get the following result

[image: Img 1]

Alternatively, if you want the noise level do be independent on the signal and have an amplitude of `0.1`, similar to what you tried to do in your question, you can remove the `u` from the noise equation.

```
u_noise = noise_fraction*(rand(size(x))-0.5);
```

You will get

[image: Img 2]

Comment: Actually, I intend to study the stability of the sech soliton pulse in this model. I got a paper in which they pointed out about this random perturbation. I have no clue.
See this paper, page 4, bottom:
|http://aip.scitation.org/doi/full/10.1063/1.4982972

Comment: @Sam I do not have access to that paper.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment under your post yet, but if you want a random perturbation, why don't you use rand or similar functions? Rand returns a scalar or array of random values from 0 to 1 that can be easily constrained to any desired intervals. I used that as a random noise in my wave problems.